# check if xml node is empty in vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

Given the following XML, how would I check to see if a particular node is empty. For instance the `<sale_price></sale_price>`.

What I am trying to do is have a if statement that will run some code if the node is empty or skip it if it is not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <Export>
        <SAVED_EXPORT>
             <id>00-6189</id>
             <price>5.46 USD</price>
             <sale_price></sale_price>
         </SAVED_EXPORT>
    </Export>
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Or do you, besides the "node empty" check, also want how to load/parse/query an XML file in VBScript but were afraid to ask? ;)

Comment: No, I have the code to load and parse but I didn't want to give more information that needed making any potential help less likely and certainly more difficult and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

```
Set oNode=oXML.selectSingleNode("//Export/SAVED_EXPORT/sale_price/")
If not(oNode is nothing) then 
   If oNode.Text="" Then

   End If
End If
```

Comment: The XPath to check the node for text contents would be `//Export/SAVED_EXPORT/sale_price[normalize-space() != '']`, otherwise the code is fine. If you omit the XPath test, you might get back a node and would have to check for both `Nothing` *and* `Trim(oNode.nodeValue) = ""` in the VBscript code.

Comment: While this probably works, for some reason in my code it is not working. I will have to re-ask my question but next time provide the full code and narrow the scope of the question down to the specific issue I am having. THX

Comment: It's not too late to clarify the question.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821714/having-trouble-spliting-the-contents-of-a-node-in-xml-when-the-contents-are-empt